# Hangfire stuck on retry attempt

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

Hangfire has stopped processing any jobs, and the culprit seems to be a job that failed, as the final record in the Hangfire.State table (I'm using SQL Server) is a 'Retry Attempt 6...'. Is there any way to remove this job, so that other jobs can continue to be scheduled/ran?

Comment: Why don't you remove this job from Hangfire panel?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Well,if you have a dashboard installed - there is a "Remove" button on failed jobs section. If you use it outside the web - try to remove a record from the database

Comment: Also you can configure retry policy with [AutomaticRetry(Attempts=1)] attribute

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the dashboard installed, but I deleted the jobs from the database. The problem is, new jobs still aren't being added. The problem could lie outside of hangfire, but there haven't been any code changes so that it leads me to think something has gone wrong in hangfire. Can you think of anything that would prevent new jobs from being created?

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled?

Comment: If you restart the app pool do the queued jobs start processing?

Comment: Yep, restarting the worker role does fix it, temporarily. The actual problem was that the function that creates the job also searches for related jobs (a list maintained in a non-hangfire lookup table), and deletes them using BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId). One of the jobs it tried to delete didn't exist, and so Hangfire just hung (https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added null handling to prevent an infinite loop if an attempt is made to delete a job
that doesn't exist.

A bug was causing it to hang when an attempt is made to delete a job which doesn't exist.

please refer to

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/535